# When both move and copy constructor is present, which one will be called?

Tags: c++, copy, move, language-lawyer

Below is class A which is full of different type of constructor.
If i comment the move constructor, then the copy constructor is called twice : once for passing an object to function fun by value and other by returning from the same function.

**Code Snippet**

class A {

```
int x;

public :
A() {
    cout<<"Default Constructor\n";
}

A(A&& a) : x(a.x){
    cout<<"Move Constructor\n";
    a.x=0;
}

A(const A& a){
    x=a.x;
    cout<<"Copy Constructor\n";
}

A fun(A a){
    return a;
}
```

};

int main() {

```
A a;
A b;
A c;
c=a.fun(b);
```

}

OUTPUT :

```
Default Constructor

Default Constructor

Default Constructor

Copy Constructor

Move Constructor
```

However, if the move constructor is present, it is called rather than copy constructor. Can anyone eloborate this with a good example, so that i will be clear on this concept.

I would appreciate your help.Thanks.

Comment: This code doesn't compile because the assignment operator (used at `c=a.fun(b)`) is deleted because you have a user-declared move-constructor. [You have to explicitly default those operators for the code to compile.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7194f49acb820000)

Comment: It did compile for me. is it necessary to define the assignment operators too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard allows a special case for the case where the expression in the `return` statement is an automatic duration variable. In this case, the constructor overloads are picked as if the expression in the `return` was an `rvalue`.

To be more precise, if the expression in the `return` statement was an automatic duration variable which was eligible for copy elision, or would be if you ignored the fact that it was a function argument, then, the compiler is required to treat it as an rvalue for the purpose of overload resolution. Note that in C++11, the `return` statement's expression needs to have the cv-unqualified type as the functions return type. This has been relaxed somewhat in C++14.

For example, in C++11, the following code calls the copy constructor of `A`, instead of the move constructor:

```
class A
{
};

class B
{
public:
B(A a) : a(std::move(a)){}
A a;
};

B f(A a)
{
return a;///When this is implicitly converted to `B` by calling the constructor `B(a)`, the copy constructor will be invoked in C++11. This behaviour has been fixed in C++14.
}
```

Comment: In the line that I marked with a comment? No, because `a` is an lvalue and the exception doesn't apply here since `a` has type `A`, while the return type of `f` is `B`. So, `a` isn't eligible for copy elision according to C++11's rules.

Comment: It should apply even in the case of compiler generated move constructor then?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. Could you be more specific please? Quote the line you are referring to and the behaviour that bothers you.

Comment: And what happens to the same return statement when there is no move and copy constructor defined? Which one will be called implicitly? This is in reference to the code which i had posted.

Answer (score 4):

in the function A fun(A a) the passed in "copy" of A is basically a temporary variable. If there is no move constructor then the return value is a copy (i.e. copy constructor).

If there is a move constructor then the compiler can perform the more efficient "move" systematics on the temp variable "A a" instead.

Comment: Why wont the compiler-generated move constructor be called ?

Comment: @Gayathri if you define a copy constructor, the compiler won't generate a move constructor.  if you define neither the compiler *may* be able to generate both, or just the move

Comment: @Ryan yes but we cant be sure if the move constructor is generated when neither is defined right? Coz it depends on whether the compiler finds a copy or move as "efficient". Did i get this right?

Comment: @Gayathri I can't think of any case where the compiler could generate a copy ctor, but not a move, but you could have move-only objects if your class has a data member that's move-only.  In that case the compiler couldn't generate a copy constructor.  If you have a data member that's non-movable such as `std::mutex` then the compiler can't generate either.  However, if you define your own copy constructor, the compiler won't generate a move constructor because it would likely be wrong

Comment: @Gayathri you can be sure

Comment: @Ryan well explained! :)

Comment: @Gayathri My answer is only a simplified answer based on your original question of "why it happens"; I don't think I can add more to Ryan or Pradhan 's comments/answer, so also +1 to these guys : )